# How to install for use on another computer?

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, games

I'm trying to install ubuntu for my gaming desktop I am currently building. My current workplace is my laptop. How do I install a temporary (yet generic) install onto the blanked hard drive without having my laptop's info pushed into it?

Comment: I would make new partition for /home , and then when you move the hardisk I would remotely erase config data stored here. Perhaps first just move them to new folder. It can probably be done with one partition for ubuntu, but I wouldn't risk it.

Answer (score 0):

Just [install Ubuntu as you normally would](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) and install all updates, but *stay away from proprietary software!*  That way, it'll just boot when you move the HDs as contrarily to Windows, *there are no drivers* just modules and these are are built into the kernel, so all hardware supported by the kernel will just work out of the box!

Once the hard drive is in the new PC, install the proprietary software like graphics modules and `ubuntu-restricted-addons`...